# Multiple Jquery tab sections on one page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having some trouble getting an "each" function to work on my jquery tabs, i have tried creating the code as a jquery plugin by using the "$this" variable but had no luck when i later realised it was already defined in the script.

I need the tabs to work per tab container as i am running these into a PHP for each loop.

The tab container id is generic-tabs, any help will be greatly appreciated!

Codepen: http://codepen.io/assasinate66/pen/NdJKZL

```js
(function($) {
  /* trigger when page is ready */
  $(document).ready(function() {

    //Tabs functionality
    //Firstly hide all content divs
    $('#generic-tabs div').hide();
    //Then show the first content div
    $('#generic-tabs div:first').show();
    //Add active class to the first tab link
    $('#generic-tabs ul#tabs li:first').addClass('active');
    //Functionality when a tab is clicked
    $('#generic-tabs ul#tabs li a').click(function() {
      //Firstly remove the current active class
      $('#generic-tabs ul#tabs li').removeClass('active');
      //Apply active class to the parent(li) of the link tag
      $(this).parent().addClass('active');
      //Set currentTab to this link
      var currentTab = $(this).attr('href');
      //Hide away all tabs
      $('#generic-tabs div').hide();
      //show the current tab
      $(currentTab).show();
      //Stop default link action from happening
      return false;
    });
  });
})(window.jQuery);
```

```css
body {
  font: 67.5% Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif;
  background: #2c3e50;
}
/*Box sizing stuff*/

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box- sizing: border-box;
}
/*Font styels*/

h1 {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 1.6em;
}
h1.callout {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 1em 0;
}
p {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: #a3a3a3;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
p strong {
  color: #555555;
}
p a {
  color: #27ae60;
  text-decoration: none;
}
/*img stuff*/

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
/*Generic styles*/

#wrapper {
  max-width: 800px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#generic-tabs {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}
/*Tab styles*/

#generic-tabs ul {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#generic-tabs ul li {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  background: #EDEDED;
  border-top: 4px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-right: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}
#generic-tabs ul li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}
#generic-tabs ul li:first-child {
  padding-left: 0;
}
/*Tab link styles*/

#generic-tabs ul li a {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 1.2em 1em;
  line-height: 16px;
  color: #BBBBBB;
}
/*Active tab styles*/

#generic-tabs ul li.active {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border-top: 4px solid #27ae60;
}
#generic-tabs ul li.active a {
  color: #333333;
}
#generic-tabs ul li.active a i {
  color: #27ae60;
}
/*Tab content styles*/

#generic-tabs .tab-content {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 3em 2em;
}
#generic-tabs .tab-content h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 650px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
  }
  h1.callout {
    font-size: 3em;
  }
  p {
    font-size: 1.4em;
  }
  #generic-tabs ul li a {
    font-size: 1.6em;
    padding: 1.2em 2em;
    line-height: 16px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.2/normalize.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div id="wrapper">
  <section id="generic-tabs">

    <ul id="tabs">
      <li>
        <a title="Home" href="#first-tab"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a> 
      </li>
      <li>
        <a title="Photos" href="#second-tab"><i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i> Photos</a> 
      </li>
      <li>
        <a title="About" href="#third-tab"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> About</a> 
      </li>
      <li>
        <a title="Contact" href="#fourth-tab"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Contact</a> 
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="first-tab" class="tab-content">
      <h1>Home</h1>
      <p><strong>Hey there, <a href="http://cliftwalker.co.uk">Jonathan Clift</a> here! I created these tabs as I find myself recreating this tab style over and over again. Use them as you please and let me know what you think.</strong>
      </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, utroque splendide an quo. Omnesque pertinacia efficiantur vix at, soleat quaeque assueverit et vis. Te sit tale eripuit corrumpit, cum ea case graeci legimus. Sea ex assentior honestatis adversarium. Mei ea dico meis
        instructior, no eum ipsum voluptatum, quodsi pertinax postulant in sed. Te eum pertinacia suscipiantur, sea eirmod sanctus ea. Vel habeo feugait ea, an apeirian adversarium nam.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="second-tab" class="tab-content">
      <h1>Twitter office photo!</h1>
      <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/twitteroffice/15437700946" title="Twitter Boston by Twitter, on Flickr">
        <img src="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2948/15437700946_3dec413dd2_b.jpg" alt="Twitter Boston">
      </a>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, utroque splendide an quo. Omnesque pertinacia efficiantur vix at, soleat quaeque assueverit et vis. Te sit tale eripuit corrumpit, cum ea case graeci legimus. Sea ex assentior honestatis adversarium. Mei ea dico meis
        instructior, no eum ipsum voluptatum, quodsi pertinax postulant in sed. Te eum pertinacia suscipiantur, sea eirmod sanctus ea. Vel habeo feugait ea, an apeirian adversarium nam.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="third-tab" class="tab-content">
      <h1>About</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, utroque splendide an quo. Omnesque pertinacia efficiantur vix at, soleat quaeque assueverit et vis. Te sit tale eripuit corrumpit, cum ea case graeci legimus. Sea ex assentior honestatis adversarium. Mei ea dico meis
        instructior, no eum ipsum voluptatum, quodsi pertinax postulant in sed. Te eum pertinacia suscipiantur, sea eirmod sanctus ea. Vel habeo feugait ea, an apeirian adversarium nam.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="fourth-tab" class="tab-content">
      <h1>Contact</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, utroque splendide an quo. Omnesque pertinacia efficiantur vix at, soleat quaeque assueverit et vis. Te sit tale eripuit corrumpit, cum ea case graeci legimus. Sea ex assentior honestatis adversarium. Mei ea dico meis
        instructior, no eum ipsum voluptatum, quodsi pertinax postulant in sed. Te eum pertinacia suscipiantur, sea eirmod sanctus ea. Vel habeo feugait ea, an apeirian adversarium nam.</p>
    </div>

  </section>

  <section id="generic-tabs">

    <ul id="tabs">
      <li>
        <a title="Home" href="#first-tab"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a> 
      </li>
      <li>
        <a title="Photos" href="#second-tab"><i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i> Photos</a> 
      </li>
      <li>
        <a title="About" href="#third-tab"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> About</a> 
      </li>
      <li>
        <a title="Contact" href="#fourth-tab"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Contact</a> 
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="first-tab" class="tab-content">
      <h1>Home</h1>
      <p><strong>Hey there, <a href="http://cliftwalker.co.uk">Jonathan Clift</a> here! I created these tabs as I find myself recreating this tab style over and over again. Use them as you please and let me know what you think.</strong>
      </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, utroque splendide an quo. Omnesque pertinacia efficiantur vix at, soleat quaeque assueverit et vis. Te sit tale eripuit corrumpit, cum ea case graeci legimus. Sea ex assentior honestatis adversarium. Mei ea dico meis
        instructior, no eum ipsum voluptatum, quodsi pertinax postulant in sed. Te eum pertinacia suscipiantur, sea eirmod sanctus ea. Vel habeo feugait ea, an apeirian adversarium nam.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="second-tab" class="tab-content">
      <h1>Twitter office photo!</h1>
      <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/twitteroffice/15437700946" title="Twitter Boston by Twitter, on Flickr">
        <img src="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2948/15437700946_3dec413dd2_b.jpg" alt="Twitter Boston">
      </a>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, utroque splendide an quo. Omnesque pertinacia efficiantur vix at, soleat quaeque assueverit et vis. Te sit tale eripuit corrumpit, cum ea case graeci legimus. Sea ex assentior honestatis adversarium. Mei ea dico meis
        instructior, no eum ipsum voluptatum, quodsi pertinax postulant in sed. Te eum pertinacia suscipiantur, sea eirmod sanctus ea. Vel habeo feugait ea, an apeirian adversarium nam.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="third-tab" class="tab-content">
      <h1>About</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, utroque splendide an quo. Omnesque pertinacia efficiantur vix at, soleat quaeque assueverit et vis. Te sit tale eripuit corrumpit, cum ea case graeci legimus. Sea ex assentior honestatis adversarium. Mei ea dico meis
        instructior, no eum ipsum voluptatum, quodsi pertinax postulant in sed. Te eum pertinacia suscipiantur, sea eirmod sanctus ea. Vel habeo feugait ea, an apeirian adversarium nam.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="fourth-tab" class="tab-content">
      <h1>Contact</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, utroque splendide an quo. Omnesque pertinacia efficiantur vix at, soleat quaeque assueverit et vis. Te sit tale eripuit corrumpit, cum ea case graeci legimus. Sea ex assentior honestatis adversarium. Mei ea dico meis
        instructior, no eum ipsum voluptatum, quodsi pertinax postulant in sed. Te eum pertinacia suscipiantur, sea eirmod sanctus ea. Vel habeo feugait ea, an apeirian adversarium nam.</p>
    </div>

  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Which `each` function? Can't find any `each` in the code above.

Comment: The tabs are working just fine! Did you included jQuery???

Comment: Please clarify your issue. The tab buttons seem to work fine.

Comment: If you scroll down to the second tab section you will see it isn't working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Just one simple problem:  *You can't use the same ID more than once.  You'll want to use class instead.*

You'll need to fix the problem on your tab containers:

```
<div id="first-section-tabs" class="generic-tabs">
</div>
```

And on the `<ul>` element inside of them:

```
<ul class="tabs"></ul>
```

And the tab `href` will need to point to unique `id`s on the divs:

```
<li><a href='#group-one-tab-one'>First</a></li>
```

And the content divs will need to have unique `id`s:

```
<div id='group-one-tab-one'>Stuff in here</div>
```

And the jQuery code will need to make sure to address each "first" div and each "first" li.  The way it's written now it will see 8 divs and 8 tabs, then show the very first of each - not the first in each collection of 4.

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.generic-tabs').each(function(index, tabs) {
      var $tabs = $(tabs);
      $tabs.find('div').hide();
      $tabs.find('div:first').show();
      $tabs.find('ul.tabs li:first').addClass('active');
    });

    $('.generic-tabs ul.tabs li a').click(function(e) {
      var $thisTab = $(e.currentTarget).closest('li');
      var $tabsContainer = $(e.currentTarget).closest('.generic-tabs');

      // notice how these variables make it almost as readable as your comments
      $tabsContainer.find('ul.tabs li').removeClass('active');
      $thisTab.addClass('active');

      // hide all tab contents
      $tabsContainer.find('div').hide();

      // show contents of tab referenced in 'href'
      var currentTab = $(this).attr('href');
      $(currentTab).show();

      return false;
    });
  });
})(window.jQuery);
```

See the final forked code here: http://codepen.io/funwhilelost/pen/GreRdY

Comment: It still isn't working with the updated code, see here: http://codepen.io/assasinate66/pen/oBVNMp

Comment: Yeah, there's a few more things you'll need to replace.  I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it doesnt work for over 2 tab sections, do you know why this could be?

Comment: @Harry-Robinson it should work as long as you continue to add unique `id` attributes to each block and remember to put the appropriate classes on each block.  Here are three: http://codepen.io/infamouse/pen/mRNEVy